# How to get a weekly view from date field in snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I have a small query mentioned below.
Need to break down a date field "DAY" to monthly and weekly wise in snowflake.

Input:

```
DAY
-------
2022-06-09
2022-04-04
```

Output

```
DAY_MONTH
----------
2022-06-01
2022-04-01  Monthly wise--- Its done
```

Here I have used

```
 DATE_FROM_PARTS( YEAR(DAY), MONTH(DAY), 1) AS DAY_MONTH
```

```
DAY_WEEK
----------
2022-06-06  
2022-04-04
```

They should be first day of working days like (Monday). How to do  that for a weekly view?

Answer (score 2):

I think you're looking for the `date_trunc` function:

```
set ts = '2022-07-07 11:14:00'::timestamp;

select date_trunc('DAY', $TS);
select date_trunc('WEEK', $TS);
select date_trunc('MONTH', $TS);
```

This is showing for a timestamp to show how it truncates to the day, but it works the same way for date types. Truncating to the week will start by the `week_start` parameter that's in effect (it will default to Monday as the start for this function):

https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/parameters.html